# Excel SUMPRODUCT ISNUMBER SEARCH Range and IGNORE Empty Blank Cells In Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

This is my problem setup in Excel.

[image: My data]

In column `G`, notice that my formula is referencing a range in column `D` and that range contains empty / blank cells. When this happens, the formula always returns `TRUE`.

[image: Look at Column G]

In column `H`, when the range referenced doesn't include empty / blank cells, it returns the correct answer `FALSE` indicating that none of the words in column `D` are in the string value in column `F`.

[image: Look at Column H]

---

**My Question**

How can I modify the formula below to ignore blank cells in a range and correctly return `FALSE` if none of the values in a range `D` is in the string value in column `F`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Rank!$D$2:$D$24,F2)))>0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D$2:$D$24,F2))*($D$2:$D$24<>"")))>0
```

[image]

Or slightly more simple:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D$2:$D$11,F2))*($D$2:$D$11<>""))>0
```

Comment: That solved it! I plan to step through this formula and evaluate it but curious if you can add insight why multiplying it by the range again and using does not contain `<>` "" works. Either way, thanks for your brilliance!

Comment: Basically you are creating an array of TRUE and FALSE ... So anywhere that a cell is blank, that part returns FALSE, which then corresponds to 0. If it helps, change the range to `$D$2:$D11` when you evaluate it.

Comment: I think I understand. It's because when `TRUE` is multiplied by `TRUE`, it returns `1`, otherwise it returns `0`.

Comment: Right you need both `TRUE` and `TRUE` within each array. And you made me realize that you can drop the double unary `--`.